# Duplicate Timeshift backups name

Tags: backup, timeshift

So I have 3 different linux distros using the same partition to store backups using timeshift.

1. Arch linux
2. Arch linux
3. Ubuntu 20.04

I installed one of the arch linux a few days ago, and now after doing all the base setup to get me started, I finally setup the timeshift in the end. But the problem is that both the arch linux installations have the same name when opening the timeshift app. See the image.[image]

See, both the arch installations have the same entry under `System`.
So, I just want a way to differentiate between the two installations of arch linux. So, what options have I got.

All are rsync backups, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1, the "quick hack":** The variable `sys-distro` in the files `info.json` in the snapshotdirs contains the system name, so you can do some scripting to change this every time a snapshot is created. (On most systems the snapshots dirs are the ones of the type `/run/timeshift/backup/timeshift-btrfs/snapshots/DIFFERENTTIMES/`)

**Option 2 (untested), the cleanest and easiest solution:** Change `/etc/lsb_release` and/or `/etc/os_release`. See also option 3 for the background on this.

**Option 3 (untested), fix it for the whole world with code:** I did some quick digging into [the timeshift source code](https://github.com/teejee2008/timeshift). (*With "quick" I mean, some educated guesses were involved...*) and this is what i found:

- `sys-distro` is generated in `write_control_file()` and is based on the passed argument `distro_full_name`
- `current_distro.full_name()` is usually passed for `distro_full_name`
- `full_name()` is generated based on vars named `dist_id`, `release` and `codename`
- These vars are all generated by `get_dist_info()`
- `get_dist_info()` gets all this info from `/etc/lsb-release` and/or `/etc/os-release` (which is why is suggested option 2)
- `write_control_file()` is defined `src/Core/Main.vala`. It's probably best to only change that last step.

Note: All options are for future backups, to do it for already created backups use option 1 and change the `info.json` files that already exist

Comment: The first one only changes the name for the first backup. The rest backups are not renamed automatically. And the second option doesn't work. And the 3rd one, I am too afraid to touch the code.

Comment: I edited my answer to clarify it a bit:The first one didn't work in your case because you only changed the most recent `info.json` file, you need to change all of them. The 2nd option will indeed have no effect on already created snapshots. It will only start having effect when you create a new snapshot. For already existing snapshots you need option 1 but instead of using a script that changes the new `info.json` after creating a backup, change all `info.json` files in the already existing snapshot dirs (manually or with a script)

Comment: thanks that worked